# Removing elements from a Map

Tags: dart, flutter

How to make iteration on the map that will remove elements on by one and then call one function after each element has been removed?

lets say I have release function

```
  final HashMap<int, bool> _instances = new HashMap<int, bool>();

  void release(dynamic instance) {
    if (_instances[instance.hashCode] != null) {
      _releaseHashCode(instance.hashCode);
      _dispatcher.dispatchEvent(PinEvent.release);
    }
  }

  void _releaseHashCode(int hashCode) => _instances.remove(hashCode);
```

Now I would like to create `releaseAll()` that will call `_releaseHashCode` for each element in the map, thus releasing it and dispatching release event.

```
  void releaseAll() {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check removeWhere

```
final Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = json.decode(jsonValue);
tempMap.removeWhere((String key, dynamic value)=> value==null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
  void releaseAll() {
    var tempMap = new HashMap<int, bool>()..addAll(_instances);
    tempMap.forEach((int hashCode, bool value) {
      _releaseHashCode(hashCode);
      _dispatcher.dispatchEvent(PinEvent.release);
    });
    tempMap.clear();
    tempMap = null;
  }
```